# How can I get this recurring script to only run if the response box isn't present?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I've written a script that checks the battery levels of my mouse and keyboard and notifies me with a response box when either drops below 35%. I have my mac run the script every 30 minutes as a daemon. It works well, but I want to make an improvement.

Currently, if I'm away from my computer for a few hours and the mouse or keyboard has dropped below the limit, I get back to a computer with many windows all telling me about the low battery. One for every 30 minutes I was away.

I want it to only run the script whilst no response boxes are active. That is, not to run while the threading is between `thread.start()` and `thread.join()`.

I have tried this method using pickle to save a boolean variable outside of the script so it has memory of whether it already notified me. The idea is that when I click done, it sets this pickle variable back to True. However, in testing it's not running the thread.join() from the first run when I run the script a second time. I guess, it's clearing the memory from the first time because it's the same script?

```
import os
import time
import threading
import pickle

limit = 35

#Load in pickle
boxStatus = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb" ))
if boxStatus:
    def getStats():
        #There is a function here that reads the battery percentages
        mouse = 30 #for testing, I set mouse to 30
        keyboard = 70 #for testing, I set keyboard to 70
        return mouse,keyboard
    
    def box(body):
        global r
        r = os.system("osascript -e 'Tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \"" + body + "\"'")

    def wait(body):
        boxStatus = False
        pickle.dump(boxStatus, open( "save.p", "wb" ))
        done = False
        while not done:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=box(body))
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
            if r == 0:
                #OK             
                boxStatus = True
                pickle.dump(boxStatus, open( "save.p", "wb" ))
                done = True
            if r == 256:
                #Cancel
                time.sleep(600) #Remind me again in 10 minutes
            
    r = None
    mouse,keyboard = getStats()[0],getStats()[1]
    #If batteries are low:
    if mouse < limit or keyboard < limit:
        wait("Batteries Low: Mouse has %s%% charge.\nKeyboard has %s%% charge." % (str(mouse),str(keyboard)))
    time.sleep(20)
```

[Here's a link to the script](https://repl.it/@AlftheElf/batteryStatus#main.py).

Could anyone please point me in the right direction as to how this is done? I'm guessing pickle is not the recommended method anyway.

Comment: `if not code: print("No Help")`

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for letting me know. I thought it was the other way around. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this today, 3 months later. I'm sure there's a much tidier solution, but I would like to explain my method anyway in case it helps anyone.

I made the launch agent daemon run a new script, instead of the one above. This script reads a txt file containing 'true' or 'false'. If the file reads 'true' it runs the python program above, but I changed the wait() function to this:

```
def wait(body):
    
    #Change status.txt to 'false' so no more instances are opened.
    with open(path+'status.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('false')
    
    done = False
    
    while not done:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=box(body))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        if r == 0:
                #OK
                #Change status back to 'true'
                with open(path+'status.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write('true')
                done = True
        if r == 256:
                #Cancel
                time.sleep(600)
```

The status file is changed, so whilst waiting for a response, the daemon runs the main program but it doesn't run the secondary script. Once I press OK in the box, the file is changed back to 'true' and the daemon is reset to run as normal.